Vite + React dev has typescript SyntaxErrors when the same isn't an error in the editor
I'm migrating an old project that used react-app-rewired to use Vite, I upgraded everything and added configs etc. but now I get this SyntaxError when I try to run the app. The same code isn't an error using tsc nor in the editor. I know for sure this isn't an error, since I have another project using Vite that has the exact same syntax, and it's not an error in that project.
Output:
[plugin:vite:react-swc] × Expected '?', got ','
 14 │ };
 15 │ 
 16 │ export const createPersistentState = <
 17 │   T extends Record<string, any>,
    ·                                ─
 18 │   K extends keyof T
 19 │ >(
 20 │   initialState: T,

Editor:

Versions
    "vite": "^5.4.3",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^4.2.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^5.0.1",

Here's my vite config:
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/',
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths(), svgr()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: './src/setupTests.ts',
    css: true,
    reporters: ['verbose'],
    coverage: {
      reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html'],
      include: ['src/**/*'],
      exclude: [],
    },
  },
});


I tried to override the esbuild version in package.json but nothing is really changing, also tried to fiddle with the esbuild config prop in vite.config.ts.
